# Credit Card Payment - secondary money receiver

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I working on an e-commerce site where I need to do something like this.
When the users is on payment page, he should be doing the following things:
- pays a fee
- authorize the payment of an amount (which could vary, but not with a big amount...)

Up to here, everything goes find with PayPal Direct payment system.

But I need more. I need that the authorized amount at some point to be directly charged by another seller (or transferred)

Any chance I can do this with PayPal Direct (such the the payment would still be made in site)? Or is there any other method?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

If you're receiving the money via DoDirectPayment you could use [MassPay](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/masspay-api-operation-nvp) or [Pay](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/pay-api-operation) to send funds to a 3rd party.  If you want the split to happen within the original payment you can use Pay by itself and set it up as a parallel or chained payment.  See the [Adaptive Payments documentation](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_adaptivepayments.pdf) for more details on that.

Comment: do Adaptive Payments work for in site credit card payment, or the user has to be redirected to PayPal?

Comment: With Adaptive Payments your only option for direct credit cards is to use "Guest Checkout".  This allows the payer to enter a CC without logging in to PayPal, but it does happen on the PayPal page rather than on your site directly.  You could setup the Adaptive Payments flow within a lightbox, though, to make it seem like less of a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I am employee) [Balanced](https://www.balancedpayments.com) will work for your use case

- capturing cards directly without sending user to a third party site
- paying out to a merchant of your choice via ACH payout at a later point in time.

The caveat is it's US only so if your outside the US let me know and I'll see if I can find any other options for you.

Comment: I am outside the USA and I couldn't find by now any alternative such that the credit card payment to be made on our site and not by redirecting the user.